# iOS: Embed Table View in other View (but table view has a complex table view controller..)

Tags: ios, tableview, subview

I'm struggling with this problem, so I need your help. Basically I've programmed a complex table view controller (with NSFetchedResults protocol etc) and already used it in my app and it worked great. Since I want now exactly this table view inside another view (so I can add a small subview at the bottom of the screen), I'm really struggling how to do this! I know by know how to embed a simple table view inside another view and link it to it's view controller.

But how can I do this in my case with as little effort as possible? I mean can I somehow use this table view controller I already have even though the superview must have its own view controller?! And how would I do that? Sorry I'm still a beginner :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a TableViewController. To add it as an subview to another ViewController's (self) view, do this:

```
TVC = <your tableViewController instance>;
[self addChildViewController:TVC];
TVC.view.frame = <your desired frame>;
[self.view addSubview:TVC.view];
```

adding the TVC as childViewController will forward UI methods of 'self' like willAppear and all to TVC.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot. But what I don't yet understand is this TVC.view.frame = your desired frame. I've layed out the layout in Xcode so what exactly would that frame be?

Comment: if you have layed it out using XIB, then no need to set frame. Go to XIB and take a tableViewController Object. Set the tableViewCOntroller objects file owner as your custom tableViewcontroller class, by changing the class name in identity inspector (3rd button from left, in right pane) then add the tableView you added to this TableViewController's view. and set the delegate and datasource accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand 100% :-( Let's put it that way: So far I have a complex TableViewController. As far as I understand (and did so far) I selected a normal ViewController and gave its view two subviews. A normal view and a table view. But from here on I don't get it. I subclassed a normal view controller for the top view controller in order to set all the necessary connections for the subviews.
But now I'm stuck…I mean in a normal table view controller I don't need to set delegate and data source, but what do I do here actually?! No idea what code to put in the top view controller.

Comment: A normal tableViewController already has the dataSource and delegate connected. After the point where you have added those two subviews. take a tabviewcontroller object. and connect its view outlet to the tableview (2nd Subview), and for that tab;eView (go to connection inspector, the last button) and connect those two data source and delegate accordingly i.e, to the class where you will be writing the  cellforRow and other such methods. Most Probably to the newly added tableViewController object.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Current situation:
- I've changed this complex table view controller to have an IBOutlet for a tableview and instead uf subclassing tableviewcontroller, it implements both tableview protocols

- My new super view controller inherits from this new CoreDataViewController and I've set the tableView Outlet to the embedded table view and from this tableview the data source and delegate to the super view controller.

Now my data gets displayed. However, it doesn't go to edit mode (which worked before)…any idea why? did I hookup something wrong?

Comment: assuming that your data is getting displayed properly, didselect method is getting called when u tap on the cell and all other normal tableview methods. Check whether you have implemented canEditRowAtIndexPath delegate method in your delegate class to return YES.